# how to convert string to variable,vb6/ c#/c++?

Tags: c#, c++, string, variables, vb6

How can I convert a string to variable in c# or C++?

example (vb6):

```
dim a as string
dim b as string

b="halo"
a="b"

msgbox a
```

this should make a output = halo

is this possible?..,

thanks for the replies

Comment: The code in your question outputs b in vb6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

I first misunderstood your answer, but now I see (thx Gserg) that you wish to find a variable based on the name. In C# you have to do this via reflection. See the following code snippet, and make sure that you have referenced System.Reflection.

```
MyNamespace.MyClass cls = new MyNamespace.MyClass();
FieldInfo fi = cls.GetType().GetField("FieldName");
string value = (string)(fi.GetValue(null, null));
Console.Out.WriteLine(value);
```

Here I look up the field "FieldName" in that class and then I return the value of the field

See also the MSDN page for GetField http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getfield(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: He's asksing how to assing to a variable a contents of another variable, given name of that variable as a string. Something like `string a = LocalVariables("b");`.

Comment: I read it as "string literal to string variable". Not sure what to make of it now. I don't see how he would mean what you mean. (And I don't think you can even do that in VB6, you can in PHP though).

Comment: This example won't work in vb6, yes. I reckon he used VB6 as pseudocode because that was the language he was most familiar with. Just look at the code, at the two consecutive assignments, and the fact that "this should make `output = halo`".

Comment: thanks for the replies

in php example

$a="b";
$b="helo";
echo $$a; //output is "helo"...

Answer (score 2):

You can not.
[Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.localvariableinfo%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) can't return name of local variable, only type and index.

Therefore, it's easiest to have a dictionary:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, string>();
d.Add("b", "helo");

MessageBox.Show(d["b"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ it is ***impossible***. In C# it may be possible due to reflection (but I am not sure how).